# want to crop the video height (1024px: 1024px). 20px above and below 20px

Tags: ffmpeg

Then change the screen size to (1024px: 1024px) without the black border. (depicted in photo)

I have tried some commands but it returns black border

[image]

Comment: Monitors with a square screen do not exist. Define better your question.

Comment: Sorry because I use google translate so may not describe what I mean.
I have a video with size 1024x1024px. I want to cut the height of the video to 40px (above 20px and below 20px). After cropping, the video will be resized to 1024x1024px. You can see the illustrations I attached.

Comment: “I have tried some commands but it returns black border” Well, wha are some of the commands? Without them you are asking us all to just do scripting for you.